# Why does function call as argument to the push cause 'Not an ARRAY reference' in Perl?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

Would somebody be so pleasant to explain why does the next thing happen? Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;
use warnings;

my @arr = (1, 2, 3);

sub func
{
    return @arr;
}

push(&func(), 4);

say @arr;
```

When I try to run it, the output is `Not an ARRAY reference at ...`.

I suppose that this is because `&func()` evaluates not to the `@arr`, but to a plain list `1, 2, 3` and `1` is treated as `ARRAY` argument to the `push`. Can somebody explain why does this happen, cause in the `push` documentation I found nothing related to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `return @arr` to `return \@arr`

Comment: @j.w.r, I know that I can do that, but why `@arr` does not work? In `push` doc it is said that it accepts `ARRAY` as it first argument, so why it does not accept it. I don't ask how to get it to work, but why this does not work.

Comment: Because `func()` does not return an array, it returns a list. The various array functions (push, pop, shift, splice) can take an array argument because they have that special functionality, but in (most) other cases, arrays collapse into a list of their elements. Which is why your push statement really looks like this: `push(1,2,3,4)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible for a sub to return an array. You are returning the result of evaluating the array in list context, which is to say you are returning a list of its content. Obviously, that's not what you want.

[`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) will now accept a reference to an array, so you could use

```
sub func {
   return \@arr;
}

push(func(), 4);
```

Note that `push` required an array literal until recently, so must use the following if you want backwards compatibility:

```
sub func {
   return \@arr;
}

push(@{ func() }, 4);
```

---

PS — Note that I removed the `&`. Why are you telling Perl to ignore the prototype of a sub that has no prototype?

Comment: As I understood functions always return a result of last expression, not the variable. Is it right?

Comment: @caligula, `:lvalue` subs would be the exception. They'll actually return the var when called in lvalue context.

Comment: @caligula, ...but `push` will still expect an array ref if you don't provide an array literal (something that starts with `@`), even if you used `sub func :lvalue { @arr }`.